# Eclipse IDE - source code for 'Outline' feature

Tags: java, eclipse

i`m actually working for a tool, which counts the methods in a class and the number of the if statements. the purpose is to estimate the quantity of test cases to write.

I've noticed that the Eclipse outline box has some interesting information and it would be really nice to get the code which produces the outline information.

[image: Eclipse Outline View]

I`ve already browsed through the Eclipse Git site, but I am a beginner and there are so many packages, can anybody tell me where I can find the source code for the Outline view, or point me in a good direction?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Eclipse Classic which contains the source code for Eclipse.  It also allows you to sniff which packages are being used by Eclipse using the plugin-spy.  You can then import the specific package and set debug points within it to view the source being executed when a specific event occurs.

The following article provides a good tutorial on the steps mentioned above:
[Eclipse Source Code Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html)

Comment: @user2148976 Glad I could help.  Make sure you have Eclipse Classic, I tried this with regular Eclipse and wasted about an hour!  The process is a little daunting the first time, but once your past the learning curve it gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html) about how to access the Java model from your plugin. [IJavaProject](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html) is the relevant API.